# Status of links to entries in body copy

Tags: entry, richtext

Is it possible to check the status of entries linked to in content from the Rich Text field? For example, the user might create a link in a paragraph to an entry that is in draft status. I would like to only display an actual link in the front end if this entry is then published.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible out-of-the-box, but you might be able to get something like that working with a shortcode approach. You could make a custom shortcode with a link parameter, and in the function for that shortcode, look up that link parameter's corresponding entry and find out its status. Then the shortcode could output a link if the entry was published, and just the original text otherwise. Here's a plugin that lets you add shortcodes: https://github.com/samhernandez/craftcms-shortcodes. If you wanted to get really fancy, you could even make a new redactor (the WYSIWYG editor Craft uses) button that inserts the shortcode instead of the normal anchor HTML.

This approach would probably take a bit of work, though. I'd be interested to see if anyone else has a better solution.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like a lot of work. Might have to reconsider. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Instead of a shortcode](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2504/177), you could also [write a filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters) which finds all links, and if they are "local", checks their status by slug, and possibly removes them.

The advantage is that the end-user doesn't have to worry about shortcodes or special redactor-buttons.

Comment: Yeah that sounds closer to what I want. Time to learn how to write plugins, I guess!

Comment: Good call - this would be much less work than my solution.